# Are OWIN Cookie & Bearer Tokens the same?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, owin, katana

When I call the OWIN `/token` endpoint I get the bearer token in the response and a set-cookie header that has a token. Are these tokens the same? If not how do I make them the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No they are not the same, the token you receive is the access token needed to access your protected API (APIs attribute with `[Authorize]`) and contains all the claims you want to encode inside it.

I've not seen token inside cookie returned when you call /token end point. Anyhow you usually depend on tokens or cookies for security not both.

Comment: to add to Taiseer's answer. Cookies are usually used with browser based clients. Tokens can be used more generically; browsers, phones, IoT devices, service to service auth.. etc